# How to exclude the features or plugin in Flutter app and only download the plugin or feature when the user need the feature?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Currently, I am using the flutter zoom plugin as dependency in my Flutter App. However, I found that after compiling, the app size is too big and inconvenient for the users to download. So, what should I do to exclude the plugin first and only download the plugin programatically when the user needs that feature? I think the eclipse has this kind of feature, so how about the Flutter?

Comment: I've not seen or read anything about this as a feature. It would essentially be DLC, Downloadable content, so try looking that up. As far as i'm aware this isn't possible.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I havent solve this problem. I think this thing should be workable as most of the games like pubg, they are having this functionality.